# How to display a 14 bit output onto a 2 digit display?

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, hdl

I have a analogue to digital converter that after conversion stores its results in two 14 bit registers. I have to display this value onto a 2 digit 7 segment display.

Here is the simulation showing the 14 bit result:

[image]

As can be seen the values are quite large for a 2 digit display. I can display these values to a one tenth of a volt. Here is the display multiplexing circuit:

```
module muxer(
     input clock,
    input reset,
    input [3:0] second,
    input [3:0] first,
    output a_m,
    output b_m,
    output c_m,
    output d_m,
    output e_m,
    output f_m,
    output g_m,
    output [1:0] cat_m
    );
 
//The Circuit for 7 Segment Multiplexing -
 
localparam N = 18;
 
reg [N-1:0]count; //the 18 bit counter which allows us to multiplex at 1000Hz
 
always @ (posedge clock)
 begin
  if (reset)
   count <= 0;
  else
   count <= count + 1;
 end
 
reg [3:0]sseg; //the 4 bit register to hold the data that is to be output
reg [1:0]cat_temp; //register for the 2 bit enable

always @ (*)
 begin
  case(count[N-1:N-2]) //MSB and MSB-1 for multiplexing
    
   2'b00 :
    begin
     sseg = first;
     cat_temp = 2'b01;
    end
    
   2'b01:
    begin
     sseg = second;
     cat_temp = 2'b10;
    end

  endcase
 end
assign cat_m = cat_temp;
 
reg [6:0] sseg_temp;
always @ (*)
 begin
  case(sseg)
   4'd0 : sseg_temp = 7'b1000000; //display 0
   4'd1 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111001; //display 1
   4'd2 : sseg_temp = 7'b0100100; //display 2
   4'd3 : sseg_temp = 7'b0110000; //display 3
   4'd4 : sseg_temp = 7'b0011001; //display 4
   4'd5 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010010; //display 5
   4'd6 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000010; //display 6
   4'd7 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111000; //display 7
   4'd8 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000000; //display 8
   4'd9 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010000; //display 9
   default : sseg_temp = 7'b0111111; //dash
  endcase
 end
assign {g_m, f_m, e_m, d_m, c_m, b_m, a_m} = sseg_temp;
 
endmodule
```

I have made it so that I can display the digits by passing the values to the `first` and `second` register. but dont know how to accomplish this with the values of `DataA` and `DataB` shown in simulation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you *want* to show? You've got a 5-digit decimal number and 2 digits to display it, you'll have to explain what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this no problem.  It's just that you won't be displaying 'digits' on the seven segment display in the sense of them being recognizable numbers in decimal or hex.  Each of the segments can represent a bit.  You have seven segments per 'digit' and 2 'digits'.  7 * 2 = 14.

Answer (score 0):

You could scroll the 5 digits you have across the two physical digits displayed.  It might be quite unpleasant to read though.